# Passing String array to PHP as POST

Tags: java, php, json, post, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to pass a string array to a PHP script as POST data but am unsure of what to do.

Here is my code for executing PHP scripts so far:

Where I am trying to pass the array:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message",message));
String [] devices = {device1,device2,device3};
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devices", devices));// <-- Can't pass String[] to BasicNameValuePair
callPHPScript("notify_devices", nameValuePairs);
```

Call PHP script:

```
public String callPHPScript(String scriptName, List<NameValuePair> parameters) {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost/" + scriptName);
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
        {
            System.out.println("DB: Error executing script !");
        }
        else {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent()));
            line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("DB: Result: " + stringBuilder.toString());
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

And the PHP script in question:

```
<?php
include('tools.php');
// Replace with real BROWSER API key from Google APIs
$apiKey = "123456";

// Replace with real client registration IDs 
$registrationIDs = array($_POST[devices]); <-- Where I want to pass array to script

// Message to be sent
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Set POST variables
$url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

$fields = array(
                'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
                'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
                );

$headers = array( 
                    'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

// Execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection
curl_close($ch);

print_as_json($result);
?>
```

Any ideas? Thanks !

**Edit**

I am trying the following but still no joy:

```
public void notifyDevices(Message message) {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    List<String> deviceIDsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String [] deviceIDArray;

    //Get devices to notify
    List<JSONDeviceProfile> deviceList = getDevicesToNotify();

    for(JSONDeviceProfile device : deviceList) {
        deviceIDsList.add(device.getDeviceId());
    }

    //Array of device IDs
    deviceIDArray = deviceIDsList.toArray(new String[deviceIDsList.size()]);
    for(String deviceID : deviceIDArray) {

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devices[]", deviceID));

    }

    //Call script
    callPHPScript("GCM.php", nameValuePairs);
}
```

This is all the "Error reporting" I have...

```
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200)
        {
            System.out.println("DB: Error executing script !");
        }
```

Comment: How about `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devices[]", device1));`, `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devices[]", device2));` ... ?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller: you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To pass an array to php in query string, you should add `[]` to identifier and add every item as separate entry, so something like this should work:

```
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devices[]", device1));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devices[]", device2));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devices[]", device3));
```

now, `$_POST['devices']` on php side will contain an array.

Comment: Hey, I am trying this but it isn't working, I don't know how to get Java to print out PHP errors so I am just getting an "Error executing script" message. I have updated my post with the code I am trying..

Comment: $_POST['devices'], not is more correct array($_POST['devices']); ¿?

Comment: It worked! It's really simple.
My client java code:
 RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("myArray[]", "abc")
                .add("myArray[]", "def")
                .add("myArray[]", "ghi")
                .build();

my php server code:
$myArray=isset($_POST['myArray']) ? $_POST['myArray'] : '';

Answer (score 5):

I think you should json encode your devices array so you get a string which you can pass it to BasicNameValuePair(...). 
In your php code, you just've to use json_decode to get back an array.

```
JSONArray devices = new JSONArray();
devices.put(device1);
devices.put(device2);
devices.put(device3);

String json = devices.toString();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devices", devices));
```

In your php code:

```
$devices = $_POST['devices'];
$devices = json_decode($devices);
```

Comment: @Tom celic
Did u solve this? I'm also having the same problem.

Comment: what is nameValuePairs

Answer (score 2):

First, you are missing single quotes when accessing the `$_POST` array in PHP. Change the line

```
$registrationIDs = array($_POST[devices]);
```

to:

```
$registrationIDs = array($_POST['devices']);
```

You should enable error logging or the output of PHP error messages for debugging using the ini value `display_errors`, `log_errors`, `error_reporting` to get noticed of such errors.

---

But even `array($_POST['devices'])` will not do what are may expecting. `array(...)` is an array initialization construct in php. Meaning that you just wrap ($_POST['devices']) into another array.

... Would like to see the output of `var_dump($_POST);`. This would give me a chance to help further..

Comment: That's not the problem, first one also works, but throws additional notice

Comment: You can set these settings to appropriate values using the `php.ini` file (globally) or per script using the function `ini_set($key, $value)`. Note my update about the `array(...)` construct