# How to HTTP post a list

Tags: http-post

I am trying to do post a list,
the data that I have look like this:

```
{  
'entity_id': '1',  
'genre_entity_ids':['6','7','8']
}
```

I have been trying all kinds of combinations:

- `entity_id=1&genre_entity_ids[0]=6&genre_entity_ids[1]=7&genre_entity_ids[3]=8`
- `entity_id=1&genre_entity_ids[]=6&genre_entity_ids[]=7&genre_entity_ids[]=8`
- `entity_id=1&genre_entity_ids=6&genre_entity_ids=7&genre_entity_ids=8`
- ...

But none of them is accepted by the server.

Please what am I doing wrong??

---

EDIT: they need to be form urlencoded

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6807180/how-to-escape-a-json-string-to-have-it-in-a-url

Comment: @iwayneo thanks iwayneo, not much, thanks anyway

Comment: What is the tech stack of the API you're posting to?

Comment: @iwayneo I don't know :-(((

Comment: This is going to be a problem because each framework serializes and deserializes differently

Comment: Is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15851761/2668136) what you're looking for?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing String array to PHP as POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851574/passing-string-array-to-php-as-post)