# How to pass string array from android to php

Tags: php, android, arrays

I have a string array and I need to pass the array data to a php file. The accepted data(php) should be stored inside the database.
I have a file where I have multiple check boxes. After selecting some check boxes I want to pass the selected data to php. 
am unable to get where am doing mistake.

Here is my code..

**First File** :callplanactivity.java

```
         public class CallplanActivity extends Activity implements
            OnItemSelectedListener {

        ListView lv;

        Context context;

        Spinner city;

        ImageButton done;

        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        private ArrayList<City> cityList;

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        JSONArray doctors_info;

        ListView listview;
        ListViewAdapter adapter, adaper2;

        String cityselected,username;

        ArrayList<Doclist> doclists;

        List<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>();

        private String URL_CITY = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/select_city.php";
        private String URL_DOCTORS = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/select_doctors.php";

        private static final String TAG_DOCDETAILS = "doctors_details";
        static final String TAG_DOC_NAME = "doc_name";
        static final String TAG_DOC_QUALI = "qualification";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_callplan);

            Intent i=getIntent();
            username=i.getStringExtra("username");
        //  Log.d("callplan", username);

            doclists = new ArrayList<Doclist>();
            city = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.city_spinner);
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

            done = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.done);

            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(CallplanActivity.this, doclists);

            listview.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

            cityList = new ArrayList<City>();

            city.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

            new GetCity().execute();

            done.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @SuppressWarnings("null")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    // StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
                    ArrayList<Doclist> doclistarray = adapter.doclist;
                    String[] outputStrArr = new String[doclistarray.size()];
                    //String[] outputStrArr = null;
                    //String[] outputStrArr2= new String[doclistarray.size()];
                    for (int i = 0; i < doclistarray.size(); i++) {

                        Doclist dc = doclistarray.get(i);

                        if (dc.isSelected()) {

                        //  Log.d("dc", "" + dc.docname);

                            outputStrArr[i] = dc.docname;

                            Log.d("sagar", "" + outputStrArr[i]);

                            Intent intent=new Intent(CallplanActivity.this,CallplanEnd.class);
                            intent.putExtra("selectedItems", outputStrArr);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                        //  Log.d("sagar not selected", "" + outputStrArr[i]);

                        }

                    }

                }

            });
        }

        private void populateSpinner() {

            // txtCategory.setText("");

            for (int i = 0; i < cityList.size(); i++) {
                cities.add(cityList.get(i).getName());
            }

            // Creating adapter for spinner
            ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cities);

            // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
            spinnerAdapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            // attaching data adapter to spinner
            city.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

        }

        private class GetCity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CallplanActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Fetching cities..");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
                String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(URL_CITY,
                        ServiceHandler.GET);

                Log.e("Response: ", "> " + json);

                if (json != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
                        if (jsonObj != null) {
                            JSONArray categories = jsonObj
                                    .getJSONArray("doctors_details");

                            for (int i = 0; i < categories.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) categories.get(i);
                                City cat = new City(catObj.getString("city"));
                                cityList.add(cat);
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("JSON Data", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                populateSpinner();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.callplan, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // new GetCategories().execute();
            Spinner city1 = (Spinner) parent;

            if (city1.getId() == R.id.city_spinner) {

                cityselected = cities.get(position);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cityselected,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                new GetDoctorsDetails().execute();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please Select City from Dropdown Box", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }

        class GetDoctorsDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

            JSONObject jsonObject;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();

            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String city_name = cityselected.toString();
                List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", city_name));

                jsonObject = jParser.makeHttpRequest(URL_DOCTORS, "POST", params1);

                Log.e("Response: ", "> " + jsonObject.toString());
                return jsonObject;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {

                adapter.doclist.clear();
                pDialog.dismiss();
                if (json != null) {
                    try {
                        doctors_info = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DOCDETAILS);

                        Log.e("Response: ", "> " + doctors_info.toString());

                        for (int i = 0; i < doctors_info.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = doctors_info.getJSONObject(i);

                            Doclist dl = new Doclist();

                            String doc_name = c.getString(TAG_DOC_NAME);
                            String qualification = c.getString(TAG_DOC_QUALI);

                            dl.setdocname(doc_name);
                            dl.setquali(qualification);

                            doclists.add(dl);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
        }
```

After selecting some values from checkboxes the data is passed to another file.

**Second File**:callplanend.java

```
        public class CallplanEnd extends Activity {

        String[] str,str1;

        ServiceHandler servicehandler;

        JSONParser jsonparser;

        String username;
        private String url_callplanends = "http://10.0.2.2/android_login_api/callplanends.php";

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent intt = getIntent();
            username = intt.getStringExtra("username");
            // Log.d("detailing", username);

            Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
            String[] resultArr = b.getStringArray("selectedItems");

            for (int i = 0; i < resultArr.length; i++) {
                if (resultArr[i] != null) {

                    str = resultArr;

                    Log.d("sagar#######", "" + str[i]);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else {

                //  str1[i]=resultArr[i];

                }
            }

            new detailparser().execute();
        }

        public class detailparser extends
                AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 JSONObject jobject=new JSONObject();
                String[] docs = str;
                String id = "1";
                String user_id = "2";
                String username = "sagar";

                Log.d("size",""+docs.length);

                List<NameValuePair> dc = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

                for (int k = 0; k < docs.length; k++) {

                    if (docs[k] != null) {

                    //  Log.d("size==--==",""+docs.length);
                    //  Log.d("size==",""+dc.size());

                        Log.d("id", "" + id);
                        Log.d("user_id", "" + user_id);
                        Log.d("username", "" + username);
                        Log.d("docs name", "" + docs[k]);


                        dc.add(new BasicNameValuePair("docslist[]", docs[k]));
                        dc.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
                        dc.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", user_id));
                        dc.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));

                        try {

                            JSONObject json = jsonparser.makeHttpRequest(
                                    url_callplanends, "POST", dc);

                            Log.d("Json-data", json.toString());

                            try {
                                int success = json.getInt("success");
                                if (success == 1) {
                                    /*
                                     * Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                     * MaindisplayActivity.class); startActivity(i);
                                     */
                                    // finish();

                                    /*Log.d("id", "" + id);
                                    Log.d("user_id", "" + user_id);
                                    Log.d("username", "" + username);
                                    Log.d("docs", "" + docs[k]);*/

                                    Log.d("success", json.toString());

                                } else {

                                    Log.d("failed", "upload failed");
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }catch(NullPointerException e){

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }



                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("null", "null"+k);
                    }

                }

                return null;
            }

        }
        }
```

and this is my **php code** to accept the array value from android..
the selected values should be passed to this php file and they must be stored inside the database.

```
        <?php
     $response = array();

     if (isset($_POST['id']) && 
     isset($_POST['user_id'])  &&
     isset($_POST['username'])
     &&  isset ($_POST['docslist'])
     ) {

     $id=$_POST['id'];
     $user_id=$_POST['user_id'];
     $username=$_POST['username'];
     $docslist = $_POST['docslist'];

     $docarray=json_decode($docslist);

     require_once 'include/DB_Connect.php';
     $db = new DB_Connect();


     $query=    mysql_query("INSERT INTO selected_docs(id,user_id,username,docname) VALUES('$id','$user_id','$username','$docarray')");
          if ($result) {
             // successfully inserted into database
             $response["success"] = 1;
             $response["message"]="successfully inserted data";
     // echoing JSON response
             echo json_encode($response);
         } else {
           //   failed to insert row
             $response["success"] = 0;
             $response["message"]="Insertion failed ";
          //   echoing JSON response
             echo json_encode($response);
         }
     }
     else {
      $response["success"] = 0;
      $response["message"]="Connection Failure";
        // echoing JSON response
         echo json_encode($response);
     }

    ?>
```

Comment: Just paste the post method code don't copy paste full class code.

Comment: ok. just wanted to clear the question and code

Comment: unable to find solution. can anyone suggest something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending the array and decoding that array in php, i converted the array to string and passed that value to php.

Here is the changes that i did with my code..

```
 dc.add(new BasicNameValuePair("docslist[]", docs.ArraytoString));
```

just changed this line and converted the Array to string and sent.

Now it works fine and the sent data is inserted into database.

Comment: Is docs a String[] ? If so, then what is a docs.ArraytoString? There's no such field in arrays. Should that be Arrays.toString(docs) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about php but in android you can use a loop to add the values of the array one by one or use a solution like in this link:
[Passing String array to PHP as POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851574/passing-string-array-to-php-as-post)