# Type error when sending 'data' in post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, typeerror

So I am trying to send a `POST` request with an object that has a property for "areas".  This will return me some bit of data that is located only around some area.  The API I am using is in php but I'm using javascript.  I have already made `POST` requests and have been getting information back, but I can't get it to work when I try to tell it what "area" I want to use.  The API says that it takes an array for the area, but when I do it in javascript, I'm getting a `TypeError`.  Here is the API:

> search_area_name: Search within specific areas.  Recommend to build a pick list to choose from if this search critieria will be used.
>           values: (array)

An example of setting up the data in php is as so:

```
$data = array (
    'partner_key' => '7e52cad4e91ee36e308d35f93a9db02b', 
    'action' => 'propertySearch',                       
    'return' => 'xml',                                  
    'search_offset' => '0', 
    'search_limit' => '100',                            
    'search_mls_id' => array('1'),
    'search_area_name'=>array("Kimball","Silver Creek Commercial"),
    'debug' => '0'
);
```

My `POST` request in javascript with my data set up:

```
app.get("/listing", function (req, res) {

    var listingID      = req.query.id, //passing these in later..
        listingAddress = req.query.address,
        listingArea    = [req.query.area];


    var data = {
        partner_key       : '7e52cad4e91ee36e308d35f93a9db02b',
        action            : 'propertySearch',
        return            : 'json',
        search_offset     : '0',
        search_limit      : '15',
        search_mls_id     : ['1'],
        search_area_name  : listingArea,
        debug             : '0'
    };

    request.post({url: url, formData: data}, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
        if (!err && httpResponse.statusCode == 200) {
            var mlsData = JSON.parse(body);
            res.render('listing', {mlsData: mlsData['data']});
        }
        else {
            return console.error('upload failed:', err);
        }
    });
});
```

So I realize that it is a lot to read, but if I take out the `search_area_name` property, all is well and I receive the exact response I expect.  When I run the script with the `search_area_name` property, I receive `TypeError`.  Any advice or input would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit, Additional Info:**

This is what my browser will display (put it all in there just in case):

```
TypeError: /Users/blazekotsenburg/WebstormProjects/ResidePC/assets/views/listing.ejs:129
    127| <%include partials/filter-suggest.ejs%>
    128| 
 >> 129| <%include partials/listingGridTemplate.ejs%>
    130| 
    131| <%include partials/footer.ejs%>

esc is not a function
    at rethrow (/Users/blazekotsenburg/WebstormProjects/ResidePC/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:285:18)
    at eval (eval at compile (/Users/blazekotsenburg/WebstormProjects/ResidePC/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:524:12), <anonymous>:268:9)
    at eval (eval at compile (/Users/blazekotsenburg/WebstormProjects/ResidePC/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:524:12), <anonymous>:270:10)
    at returnedFn (/Users/blazekotsenburg/WebstormProjects/ResidePC/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:555:17)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/blazekotsenburg/WebstormProjects/ResidePC/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:203:34)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/blazekotsenburg/WebstormProjects/ResidePC/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:412:10)
    at View.render (/Users/blazekotsenburg/WebstormProjects/ResidePC/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:128:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/blazekotsenburg/WebstormProjects/ResidePC/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/Users/blazekotsenburg/WebstormProjects/ResidePC/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/blazekotsenburg/WebstormProjects/ResidePC/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:971:7)
```

and the `listingGridTemplate.ejs`, which is where I guess it is failing even though it works when that property is not passed, is as so:

```
<div class="row grid-list"><!-- Begin First Row-->
    <div class="container">

        <h1 id="featured-listings">Featured Listings</h1>

        <% mlsData.forEach(function(listing) { %>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">

                <div id= "<%= listing['list_id']%>">

                    <% var listingImage = listing['photos'].split(",");%>
                    <% if (!listingImage[0]) { %>

                        <div class="thumbnail photo-card">

                            <%include listingGridStatus.ejs%>

                            <a href="/listing?id=<%=listing['list_id']%>?area=<%=listing['area_name']%>?address=<%=listing['address']%>">

                            <img class="img-responsive" src="https://source.unsplash.com/wtrAchtpc-w">

                                <p class="no-image-header">No Images <i class="fa fa-frown-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>

                                <section class="photo-card-info-spec-row1">
                                    <span class="photo-card-price">
                                        $<%= listing['price'].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") %>
                                    </span>
                                    <span class="photo-card-info">
                                        <%include listingGridPropCheck.ejs%>
                                    </span>
                                </section>

                                <section class="photo-card-info-spec-row2">

                                    <span class="photo-card-dom">

                                        <span class="dom">dom:</span>

                                        <%= listing['days_on_market']%>
                                    </span>

                                    <span class="photo-card-punct">|</span>

                                    <span class="photo-card-address">

                                        <%= listing['address']%>,
                                        <%= listing['city']%>,
                                        <%= listing['state']%>
                                    </span>
                                </section>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <% } else { %>

                        <div class="thumbnail photo-card">

                            <%include listingGridStatus.ejs%>

                            <a href="/listing?id=<%=listing['list_id']%>&address=<%=listing['address']%>&area=<%=listing['area_name']%>">

                                <img class="img-responsive img-drop-shadow" src="http://www.realcove.net/<%= listingImage[0]%>">

                                <section class="photo-card-info-spec-row1">
                                    <span class="photo-card-price">
                                        $<%= listing['price'].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") %>
                                    </span>

                                    <span class="photo-card-info">
                                        <%include listingGridPropCheck.ejs%>
                                    </span>
                                </section>

                                <section class="photo-card-info-spec-row2">

                                <span class="photo-card-dom">

                                    <span class="dom">dom:</span>

                                        <%= listing['days_on_market']%>
                                    </span>

                                    <span class="photo-card-punct">|</span>

                                    <span class="photo-card-address">
                                        <%= listing['address']%>,
                                        <%= listing['city']%>,
                                        <%= listing['state']%>
                                    </span>
                                </section>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <% } %>
                </div>
            </div>
        <% }); %>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: What framework is `request.post()` from? That's not a Javascript built-in function.

Comment: Is this Node.js?

Comment: Yes this is node.js, sorry I forgot to put that as I already had so much

Comment: @Barmar I believe this is node and express

Comment: yes, node express and request

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not posting this as a comment (do not have 50 rep yet). A suggestion I could give you is for you to put some debugging messages to see what exactly gets passed to your variables.

put a `console.log([req.query.area]);` just above your var definitions, and put one more `console.log(listingArea)` just before your post request. Check your console if you are getting some gibberish values and that should be your starting point. Hope this helps you out!

EDIT:
I believe I found a relevant answer that might help you out.
Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/15851761/7654934

Comment: I have done this, it will print `['The Canyons']` when I do it.  (or whatever other data, but it is an `Array` of type `string`)

Comment: @blizzyb hmmm maybe go over this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15851761/7654934) and see if that helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you simply need to remove the square brackets surrounding req.query.area

```
listingArea    = req.query.area;
```

Comment: I wish this were the case but I have tried that as well, still returns a `TypeError` :(

Comment: Have you tried writing the array hard coded? Still error?

Comment: Yea that still gives me an error.. that's why I'm so confused haha